# mongo aggregation framework get transactions in sequence

Tags: mongodb, sequence, aggregation-framework

How do i do this in mongo aggregation framework?
 given these  records

```
record 1. {id:1,action:'clicked',user:'id', time:'1'}
record 2. {id:2,action:'video play',user:'id',time:'2'}
record 3. {id:3,action:'page load',user:'id',time:'3'}
record 4. {id:4,action:'video play',user:'id',time:'4'}
record 5. {id:1,action:'clicked',user:1id', time:'5'}
record 6. {id:2,action:'video play',user:'id',time:'6'}
```

now, how do i get the all "video play" that are after clicked action? anybody come across with this kind of aggregation?

Comment: Hmm that is indeed an interesting...and unique problem, what's the use case if I may ask?

Comment: The use case is to separate view count of a videos watched on page load vs to videos watched as a result of user interaction on the page.

Comment: Can you explain what it means to have "video play" after clicked action? I want a sample sequence in the selection of records you gave.

Comment: So in the records above let's say time:1 and time:6 are the records as a result of action:clicked so the video play occurred because of clicks are at time:1 and time:6 and not time:4

Answer (score 1):

You will need to redesign your schema. I can think of two approaches. In your application you can track the click path of a session. When you insert an action to your collection, you will need to also track the previous interaction. Once you have this, then you just need to do something like `db.actions.find({prevAction:"clicked",action:"video play"}).count()`. This will be very fast.

Alternatively, if you decide you like to track session click path information, you may have a document like:

```
{_id:sessionid
user:usderid
actions:[
{...login}
{...click link}
{...play video}
]}
```

You can create this collection by doing upserts. Make sure you keep the action subdocuments small so you don't exceed the 16MB limit for standard documents. Also set the collection's padding factor to "powersof2."

Once you have this collection, you can pull out these documents to get some interesting info. The specific aggregation that you want to do would be more complex on this collection than the suggestion that I previously made though. You will need to create a MR process that may run periodically behind the scenes to calculate what you want (emit key value  only if the area contains the expected sequence of actions).

Comment: I'd phrase "Also set a padding factor to 'powersof2'" differently as it's actually something you need to enable it on a collection as it's described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#usePowerOf2Sizes

Comment: edit: Also set the collection's padding factor to "powersof2."